# Java runtime load.exec not working

Tags: java, pdf

I want the pdf to be opened automatically after creating it.I have written the following code.
but it is giving the following error:

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

The code:

```
Runtime load = Runtime.getRuntime();
                  load.exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Foxit Software\\Foxit Reader\\Foxit Reader.exe"+
                        " D:\\Movie\\eclipse-jee-juno-win32-x86_64\\eclipse\\Webcontent\\export\\pdf_exported_2014_05_08_080211.pdf");
```

Comment: Whenever you've got an error message, it'd be of great help if you actually told us what the error is. It tends to be more informative than "an error".

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Are you sure the file exists at the given path?

Comment: ye sure because when i tried to exec D:\\Movie\\eclipse-jee-juno-win32-x86_64\\eclipse\\Webcontent\\export\\pdf_exported_2014_05_08_080211.pdf in  ctrl + r(run) it will open the file

Comment: It's *definitely* the spaces in, amongst others, "Program Files (x86)". The error message even tells you that: `Cannot run program "C:\Program"`. Note that your 'working' line does not refer to folders or filenames containing spaces. I'd have posted this as an answer, except I'm not Java savvy enough to suggest a solution. Escape them? Double-quote the entire path?

Comment: I have already double-quote the entire path

Comment: I got the solution.
Process p = Runtime
         .getRuntime()
         .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler D:\\Movie\\eclipse-jee-juno-win32-x86_64\\eclipse\\Webcontent\\export\\pdf_exported_2014_05_08_080211.pdf");
      p.waitFor();